# Openstack + Mongodb  + Elasticserach миграция

Tags: mongodb, java, elasticsearch

Наверное, не так составил заголовок, но не знаю, как ещё.
В общем, какая проблема - человек сделал java rest сервис. Потом человек пропал, и возникла необходимость перейти на другой сервер. НО документации нет, и вообще неизвестно, какие ходы делал тот человек. Всё, что я выяснил, это - на сервере стоит openstack с виртуалкой, к которой прицеплены два тома - mongodb и elasticsearch. Код на сервер деплоится средствами jenkins. И потом как-то запускается rest сервис.
Может, у кого есть идеи, что почитать? Или кто-то уже сталкивался с подобными конфигурациями и может описать путь?